# PHP - Converting XML to array misses some information from XML string

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I am using curl to get an external XML document and convert it to an array.

The code works almost perfect, apart from one node in the XML isn't being processed and put in my array.

Under `<drivers>` there is a code for each driver: `<driver code="TM1">` but this doesn't get picked up by my array as an @attribute array like the others such as `<collection date="20160324">`

Does anybody know why this is happening?

XML:

```
<findit xmlns="http://www.URL.COM" version="8" type="TIX" date="20160323">
  <account code="XXXXXX">
    <customers>
      <customer code="12345">
        <status code="0">Success</status>
        <logistic-jobs>
          <logistic-job id="12345" date="20160324" status="PLA" modified="201603231420">
        <number>
          <number1>479599</number1>
          <number3>11221</number3>
        </number>
        <collection date="20160324" time="0500">
          <name>JOHN SMITH</name>
          <address1>UNIT 3 DAVEY ROAD</address1>
          <address2>FIELDS END BUSINESS PARK</address2>
          <address3>GOLDTHORPE</address3>
          <address4>ROTHERHAM</address4>
          <address5>S63 0JF</address5>
        </collection>
        <delivery date="20160324" time="1200">
          <address1>EXAMPLE</address1>
          <address2>GLENEAFLES FARM</address2>
          <address3>GLENEAGLES CLOSE</address3>
          <address4>STANWELL, MIDDLESEX</address4>
          <address5>TW19 7PD</address5>
        </delivery>
        <extra>
          <address1>45FT C/SIDER</address1>
          <address2>No</address2>
          <address4>CEMENT</address4>
        </extra>
        <drivers>
          <driver code="TM1">DAVE SMITH (DAYS)</driver>
        </drivers>
        <load weight="27600.00" volume="0.00">
          <pallets full="23" half="0" quarter="0" blue="0" oversize="0"/>
        </load>
      </logistic-job>
    </logistic-jobs>
  </customer>
</customers>
</account>
</findit>
```

PHP:

```
$job_array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), true);

if(is_array($job_array['account']['customers']['customer'])) {

    // Foreach customer in array
    foreach($job_array['account']['customers']['customer'] as $i => $customer) {

        // If status is set to success
        if($customer['status'] == "Success") {

            // For each job
            foreach($customer['logistic-jobs']['logistic-job'] as $i => $job) {

                echo '<pre>'; print_r($job); echo '</pre>';

            }

        }

    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12345
        [date] => 20160324
        [status] => PLA
        [modified] => 201603231420
    )

[number] => Array
    (
        [number1] => 479599
        [number3] => 11221
    )

[collection] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20160324
                [time] => 0500
            )

        [name] => JOHN SMITH
        [address1] => UNIT 3 DAVEY ROAD
        [address2] => FIELDS END BUSINESS PARK
        [address3] => GOLDTHORPE
        [address4] => ROTHERHAM
        [address5] => S63 0JF
    )

[delivery] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20160324
                [time] => 1200
            )

        [address1] => EXAMPLE
        [address2] => GLENEAFLES FARM
        [address3] => GLENEAGLES CLOSE
        [address4] => STANWELL, MIDDLESEX
        [address5] = TW19 7PD
    )

[extra] => Array
    (
        [address1] => 45FT C/SIDER
        [address2] => No
        [address4] => CEMENT
    )

[drivers] => Array
    (
        [driver] => DAVE SMITH (DAYS)
    )

[load] => Array
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 21509.00
                [volume] => 0.00
            )

        [pallets] => Array
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [full] => 52
                        [half] => 0
                        [quarter] => 0
                        [blue] => 0
                        [oversize] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: I think [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php#80855) will be somewhat helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply @xmike but I have already tried this and it still hasn't given me the 'code' that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple answer for you: **don't convert XML to an array**. SimpleXML has a really useful API for traversing through the XML document and finding the data you want; throw away the horrible `json_decode(json_encode(` hack and look at the [examples in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

In this case, `echo $driver` would give you the contents (driver name) and `echo $driver['code']` would give you the attribute value; clearly, a plain array can't have that convenient magic, which is why converting to one is giving you problems.

Just remember that `print_r` will also hide things from you, and you might want [a dedicated debugging function](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug/).

Here's an example (with [live demo](https://3v4l.org/fljJA)) of getting the code and name of each driver:

```
$job_simple = simplexml_load_string($xml);

if(isset($job_simple->account->customers->customer)) {

    // Foreach customer in array
    foreach($job_simple->account->customers->customer as $i => $customer) {

        // If status is set to success
        if((string)$customer->status == "Success") {

            // For each job
            foreach($customer->{'logistic-jobs'}->{'logistic-job'} as $i => $job) {
                echo "<ul>\n";
                foreach ( $job->drivers->driver as $driver ) {
                     echo "<li> {$driver['code']}: $driver\n";
                }
                echo "</ul>\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```